# Change wordpress title via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyway to change the blog title and description using PHP code? Can't find any references. Trying to use that for an theme option panel. Tnx.

Comment: Its there in wordpress admin itself. WpAdmin-> Settings ??

Comment: _"using PHP code"_ What have you tried so far?

Comment: Basicly i'm sending a string from my theme option panel but i dunno how to attach it to the title.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, There's a function called `wp_title` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)).
Look for the "header.php" file in your template's directory.

Luckily for us, there's always a filter for this function.
You can read more about it over here [wp_title filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title).

If you're using a default template, check out the `functions.php` file
which is already using that filter. (So you rather change it instead of adding another one)